# Why do numbers in a table appear as oldstyle figures when using Palatino/Euler Math?

Tags: tables, oldstylenums, mathpazo, eulervm, euler

I'm using the Palatino font in combination with Euler Math.  In most cases, digits in math mode appear as standard lined figures.  However, in tables, they appear as oldstyle figures.  Here's an example:

[image]

Why are these numbers rendered differently?  How can I make the digits in the table match the other math digits?

Here's the code for the screenshot above:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.025}
\usepackage[euler-digits,small]{eulervm}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Normally, math digits appear as lined figures:
\[
    x = 1234567890
\]

However in a table, numbers appear as oldstyle figures:
\[
    x  =  
    \left \{
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            0123 & 4567 \\
            8910 & 0101
        \end{tabular}
    \right \}
\]

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: tabular switches to textmode, use array in math.

Comment: Thanks, @UlrikeFischer, that worked!  If you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept.

Comment: On a side note, there’s also the `eulerpx` package for a Euler/Palatino mashup, or Khaled Hosny’s OpenType math font Neo Euler, usable with `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`tabular` switches to textmode, use `array` in math:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
\linespread{1.025}
\usepackage[euler-digits,small]{eulervm}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Normally, math digits appear as lined figures:
\[
    x = 1234567890
\]

and in an array too:
\[
    x  =  
    \left \{
        \begin{array}{cc}
            0123 & 4567 \\
            8910 & 0101
        \end{array}
    \right \}
\]

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]